# Can I mock or disable CURL on OpenCart?

Tags: php, curl, opencart, web-hosting

My host provider recently changed their settings so that **CURL is now disabled** and I **cannot use the OpenCart dashboard any more**.

I have read around that CURL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work.

Is there a way to **mock CURL** so that my OpenCart instance will keep working?

P.S. Note that I am changing hosting provider, but I need a workaround for a week or so.

Comment: For a week just poke the db directly